# Calculate average speed from array of Coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gps

```
     //Global var
     ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    //Adds a marker on the current position found in LatLng
    myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //Sets the marker to the position of LatLng and zooms the camera in on the location
    LocationMarker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates));
    float zoomLevel = 12.0f;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, zoomLevel));

    //Adds marker on each location update
    points.add(myCoordinates);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(points.get(0))
            .title("Starting Location")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));

    //Draws a polyline between the location updates stored in points.
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .addAll(points)
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.RED));

    //gets speed from Location and converts it to Km/h
    speedText.setText(String.format("%.0f - Km/h", location.getSpeed() * 3.6));

}
```

This is my onLocationChanged function. This stores the coordinates into my array called points every time it updates. It also draws and a Polyline on each update, calculates my speed in km/h and adds a marker at my array location [0] which is my starting location. This all works fine and perfect for what I need to it do.

Is it possible to calculate the average speed from this?

Comment: you'll need to calculate speed between every two consecutive coordinates, and then calculate average speed

Comment: Also look at SphericalUtil.computeLength - it takes a list of LatLng's and returns total path length - so this length and time of first point and current time you can compute average speed.  Btw your 'addPolyLine' keeps adding a progressively longer polyline without removing prior ones which you would not visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create another global list and insert the value of getSpeed();

```
speedArray.add(Double.parseDouble(location.getSpeed()));
```

And create a function that its called in the end of onLocationChanged and it calculates the average speed everytime;

Comment: `getSpeed` will return valid values only if you set them using `setSpeed` before. Otherwise it will return 0 (zero).

Comment: Thanks @dan I suposed he previously had the speed value.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the `location` object, that you used, is received by the callback. He needs to compute the speed, using the previous GPS location.

Comment: Thanks Antonio ! Wasn't too sure where to start with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. But you need to record a bit more data, like:

- the previous location coordinates.
- the current time of the location sample.

Using the above information you can use the following formula:
`speed = distance / time`

Where `distance` will be `currentGPSPoint - previousGPSPoint` and `time = currentTime - previousTime`

This will give you the average speed between two locations. If you need an overall average you can save all the calculated speeds and calculate an average. Or just store the initial location and always compute the speed from the initial location to the current location.